# Trouble Avoiding Microsoft Outlook's Email Warning

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-access-2007

I have a set of records in Microsoft Access that I am trying to send in an Email.  The email feature works great. Except a warning message pops up every time a message is ready to send, and the user has to click "Allow" or "Deny" for every email sent.  I looked up a workaround, and have been following the tutorial for it:
  http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Outlook-Send-E-mail-Without-Security-Warning.
My problem is that when I put my message in the function it always returns false, and the message fails.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim sendMail As Boolean
Dim strMessage As String
strMessage = Some Message
sendMail = FnSafeSendEmail(![Email Id], "Subject", strMessage)
```

The entire "FnSafeSendEmail" function can be found in the link provided.  These are the parameters though.

```
Public Function FnSendMailSafe(strTo As String, _
                            strCC As String, _
                            strBCC As String, _
                            strSubject As String, _
                            strMessageBody As String, _
                            Optional strAttachments As String) As Boolean
```

The error, "Object doesn't support this property or method", is thrown on this line of the function.

```
Dim blnSuccessful As Boolean
blnSuccessful = objOutlook.FnSendMailSafe(strTo, strCC, strBCC, _
                                            strSubject, strMessageBody, _
                                            strAttachmentPaths)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.  I had to disable security checks for macros in Microsoft Outlook's trust center.